# Appending a value to start of list

Tags: python, list, encryption, transpose

Currently working on a 2D transposition cipher in Python. So I have a list that contains an encoded message, like below:

```
['BF', 'AF', 'AF', 'DA', 'CD', 'DD', 'BC', 'EF', 'DA', 'AA', 'EF', 'BF']
```

The next step is taking that list, splitting it up and putting it into a new matrix with regards to a keyword that the user enters. Which I have below:

```
Enter the keyword for final encryption: hide
  H    I    D    E
['B', 'F', 'A', 'F']
['A', 'F', 'D', 'A']
['C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
['B', 'C', 'E', 'F']
['D', 'A', 'A', 'A']
['E', 'F', 'B', 'F']
```

**What I would like to do next and haven't done** is take each of the columns above and print them in alphabetical order, therefore getting another cipher text, like below:

```
  D    E    H    I
['A', 'F', 'B', 'F']
['D', 'A', 'A', 'F']
['D', 'D', 'C', 'D']
['E', 'F', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'A', 'D', 'A']
['B', 'F', 'E', 'F']
```

Here's my code:

```
def encodeFinalCipher():
    matrix2 = []
    # Convert keyword to upper case
    keywordKey = list(keyword.upper())

    # Convert firstEncryption to a string
    firstEncryptionString = ''.join(str(x) for x in firstEncryption)

    # Print the first table that will show the firstEncryption and the keyword above it
    keywordList = list(firstEncryptionString)
    for x in range(0,len(keywordList),len(keyword)):
        matrix2.append(list(keywordList[x:x+len(keyword)]))

    # Print the matrix to the screen
    print ('  %s' % '    '.join(map(str, keywordKey)))
    for letters in matrix2:
        print (letters)

    return finalEncryption
```

I have traversed the 2D matrix and got all the column entries like below:

```
    b = [[matrix2[i][j] for i in range(len(matrix2))] for j in range(len(matrix2[0]))]
    for index, item in enumerate (b):
        print("\n",index, item)

OUTPUT:------
 0 ['B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E']

 1 ['F', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'F']

 2 ['A', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B']

 3 ['F', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'F']
```

How would I append each letter of the keywordKey (e.g. 'H' 'I' 'D' 'E') to the list where the numbers 0,1,2,3 are?

Or probably a more efficient solution. How would I put the letters into the keywordKey columns when creating the matrix? Would a dictionary help here? Then I could sort the dictionary and print the final cipher.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> lst = [['B', 'F', 'A', 'F'],
['A', 'F', 'D', 'A'],
['C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
['B', 'C', 'E', 'F'],
['D', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
['E', 'F', 'B', 'F']]
>>> key = 'HIDE'
```

Sort `xrange(len(key))` or `range(len(key))` using the corresponding values from `key` and then you will have a list of indices:

```
>>> indices = sorted(xrange(len(key)), key=key.__getitem__)
>>> indices
[2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Now all we need to do is loop over the list and apply these indices to each item using `operator.itemgetter` and get the corresponding items:

```
>>> pprint([list(itemgetter(*indices)(x)) for x in lst])
[['A', 'F', 'B', 'F'],
 ['D', 'A', 'A', 'F'],
 ['D', 'D', 'C', 'D'],
 ['E', 'F', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'A', 'D', 'A'],
 ['B', 'F', 'E', 'F']]
#or simply
>>> pprint([[x[i] for i in indices] for x in lst])
[['A', 'F', 'B', 'F'],
 ['D', 'A', 'A', 'F'],
 ['D', 'D', 'C', 'D'],
 ['E', 'F', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'A', 'D', 'A'],
 ['B', 'F', 'E', 'F']]
```